# Send Outlook email if criterias are met in Excel cells

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I need to send an email with Excel with two conditions.

- Cell D2 must be >= 1
- Cell E2 must be ="".

I've the first condition done, but not the second one

The code is:

```
'PRAZO Etapa 4
Public Sub EnviarEmailEt4()    

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim Body As String

  Worksheets("Incidentes2019").Select
  Range("D4").Select
  Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
     If ActiveCell >= 1 And ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = "" And InStr(2, Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 10), "@") > 0 Then

        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
             .To = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 10).Value
             .CC = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 11).Value
             .BCC = ""
             .Subject = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value
            If (ActiveCell = 1) Or (ActiveCell = 2) Then
                .Body = "ALERTA PRAZO ETAPA 4!!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Nº GQE " & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value & " - " & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value
            ElseIf (ActiveCell >= 3) Then
                .Body = "ULTRAPASSADO PRAZO ETAPA 4!!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Nº GQE " & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value & " - " & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value
            End If
            .Send 'Display

        End With
     Set OutMail = Nothing
     Set OutApp = Nothing
     MsgBox "Alerta Etapa 4 enviado - " & Format(Now, "HH:MM") & vbNewLine & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value
     End If

    Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, ActiveCell.Column).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: So the email is only sent in the case D2 >= 1 *And* E2 = ""? If that is so, make an If statement `If Range("D2") >= 1 And Range("E2" = vbNullString Then Call EnviarEmailEt4`

Comment: and where do I put it?

Comment: For what I can see on your code, you are trying to send multiple emails from a list on your worksheet, is that right? Can you add a screenshoot of the worksheet containing these criterias? (do not copy the emails)

Comment: Sure! it is the link named "image"

Comment: Try the answer i've just posted... Let me know if you need understanding the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select cell on the right (like pressing the arrow in excel) using `Range.offset()` property. Try to change your IF statement to the following:

```
If ActiveCell >= 1 And ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) <> "" Then
```

EDIT:
in response to the change in your question: here is a working approach to set mailbody based on the activecell value:

```
    If (ActiveCell = 1) Or (ActiveCell = 2) Then
        MailBody = "ALERTA PRAZO ETAPA 4!!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Nº GQE " & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value & " - " & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value
    ElseIf (ActiveCell >= 3) Then
        MailBody = "ULTRAPASSADO PRAZO ETAPA 4!!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Nº GQE " & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value & " - " & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value                            
    End If
```

Comment: Glad to help. If it answers your question please mark as answer.

Comment: Hi @Spring Filip! 
Can you please tell me how to change the message sent in the e-mail in order to: 
if ActiveCell is = 1 or 2 then "AAAA"; 
if ActiveCell is >= 3 then message "BBBB"

Comment: You could try something like this: `dim message as string` on top and then `If (ActiveCell = 1) OR (ActiveCell = 2) Then message = "AAAA" ElseIf (ActiveCell >= 1) Then message = "BBBB" End If`. In the mail set `.Body = message`

Comment: (...) Dim OutApp As Object Dim OutMail As Object Dim message As String (...) .Body = If (ActiveCell = 1) Or (ActiveCell = 2) Then message = "AAA" ElseIf (ActiveCell >= 3) Then message = "BBBB" End If End If Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, ActiveCell.Column).Select Loop End Sub 

Like that?

Comment: I've changed the code upside. That's what I have right now and it doesn't work. Can you identify what's wrong?

Comment: You cannot do `.Body = If ...`. Also there should be only one `End If`.

Comment: So, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you can check in a loop outside the mail procedure if the cells meet your criteria, if so then you send the mail:

```
Option Explicit
Sub SendingMails()

    Dim ws As Worksheet 'always declare worksheets and workbooks to avoid using select
    Dim SendTo As String, SendSubject As String, FirstData As String, SecondData As String 'here, variables for the items to fill on your mail
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long 'Here you have the lastrow of the worksheet and another variable for a loop

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change Sheet1 for the name of the sheet where you keep the data
    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row 'this will check the last row with data on the column 4 (D)
        For i = 2 To LastRow 'starting from row 2 to the last one with data
            If .Cells(i, 4) >= 1 And .Cells(i, 5) <> vbNullString Then 'here you check if column D cell has 1 or higher and if column E cell is empty
                SendTo = .Cells(i, 10)
                SendSubject = .Cells(i, 3)
                FirstData = .Cells(i, 2)
                SecondData = .Cells(i, 3)
                Call EnviarEmailEt4(SendTo, SendSubject, FirstData, SecondData)
            End If
        Next i
    End With


End Sub
Sub EnviarEmailEt4(SendTo As String, SendSubject As String, FirstData As String, SecondData As String)

    'as you can see above, i've declared variables inside the procedure which will be taken from the previous one

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
        .to = SendTo
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = SendSubject
        .Body = "ALERTA FIM DE PRAZO ETAPA 4!!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Nº GQE " & FirstData & " - " & SecondData
        '.Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName 'Anexar este ficheiro
        '.Attachments.Add ("") 'Anexar outro ficheiro
        .send 'Display
    End With
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    MsgBox "     Alerta Et4 enviado - " & Format(Now, "HH:MM") 'I Would avoid alerting in each loop if there are lots of mails

End Sub
```

Comment: can you tell me if the msgbox can all be in only one msgbox?

Comment: As for your code I would only pop up a message alerting on how many emails have been sent since you have nothing different for each mail. Just a warning with the time.

Comment: Now I have. the message has one part that is the same and one part that is the active cell, this last  one is always different!
I updated the code.

Comment: Now I have. the message has one part that is the same and one part that is the active cell, this last one is always different! I updated the code.